# Tesseract - Compiling for iOS: libs not created

Tags: ios, tesseract

I'm trying to compile tesseract for iOS according to this [howto](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/).
Unfortunately the "lib" folder is empty after the build, but I can't figure out the problem.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1 and iOS SDK 6.1.

The last error I can find in the output is:

```
configure: error: leptonica library missing
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. 
ar: creating archive libtesseract_all.a
ar: *.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "configure: error: leptonica library missing" doesn't give you a hint?

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky I've downloaded the leptonica project, as described in the tutorial. So I don't know (or see) why it breaks.

Comment: ..but script cannot find it. Check pathes, and check building script's LEPTON_LIB parameter, LEPTON_LIB="`pwd`/leptonica-1.69"

Comment: I tried the good old windows solution: Restarted my MacBook. Now it works and the .a files in the lib folder are created. In the log (in a compile step) I saw something like "resource unavailable", so I tried the restart. I have no idea why a restart helped. So restarting seems to be the answer...but it's not a very nice answer (on a unix system..on windows it seems to be the perfect solution for everything...just kidding..)